# ReactiveMongo + TypeSafe Stack => Production?

Tags: mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.0, typesafe-stack

Can I presently somehow integrate ReactiveMongo with TypeSafe Stack? As I know, ReactiveMongo requires Play! 2.1 and it is not yet production-ready? Does anyone have any positive experience along this way? Or, if I am too dreamy today, then maybe some estimation on when will this combo become viable?

Comment: And BTW, Reactive Mongo **does not** require Play.

Comment: @i.am.michiel Well, yeah, I think you're right, but I read it somehow depends on its JSON lib.. did not try yet though, so can't really tell.

Comment: I can confirm it does not depend on play at all (including json). It only depends on the play-iteratee lib, which has no deps on play itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The combo works. Play 2.1 is in RC1 so it's quite stable, and Reactive Mongo is the best idea I've seen since sliced bread for real time apps.

That said, it's not an official release (yet) so using it in production has a certain risk. If your application is non-critical or a hobby project, use it, it will be fine. Otherwise, don't.

Comment: Also, I did not find any info on TypeSafe, regarding the versioning of Play in the Stack. Looks like they still distribute Play 2.0.2 with the standard bundle... but there is no any versioning info on the website. How will I know they have officially switched to Play 2.1?

Comment: They will probably announce it when they switch to 2.1 but since 2.1 and akka and Slick among others are waiting for Scala 2.10, all these announcements will probably be linked.